# Issue passing parameters while calling jenkins job remotely

Tags: json, jenkins, curl, parameter-passing

I am using curl to call Jenkins job remotely and passing parameters. But it is not taking parameters.

curl -g -X POST --user user:token https://locahost:8080/job/testing/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN --data-urlencode json='{"parameter":[{"DATE":${DATE}},{"TIME":${TIME}},{"VALUE":${VALUE}}]}'

Answer (score 1):

My Jenkins instance (2.164.2) also required a crumb, which I first got via this first "curl". This example works for me.
Note that I have the "?" and "&"'s escaped, as I'm in a bash shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

crumb=$(curl --user username:password -s 'https://<hostname>/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
curl -g -X POST -H "$crumb" --user username:password https://<hostname>/job/ParamTest/buildWithParameters\?token=TOKEN\&Param1=foo\&Param2=bar
```